# Search for Multiple values but stop search when found exact match

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-query

So I have implemented a basic search using elasticSearch.
How do I give a search query such that:

if ( get exact match AccountId:CMRZ )

{

```
  return me just that one account with id:CMRZ
```

}

else

```
   return me accounts that have ids like id:CMRZ12, id:98CMRZ12 etc.
```

I have tried the following but it does not work if I have a hyphen in my id:
http://localhost:9200/account/useraccounts/_search?q=id:"* CMRZ*"

if I send  <--> result is

1-CMRZ-121 <--> 1-CMRZ-121

1-CMRZ-   <--> 1-CMRZ-121 ,1-CMRZ-165

BUT

1-CMR <--> NULL RESPONSE

Thus now i know the problem is with the hyphen. Any way of preventing this such that I get the following answer?

1-CMR <--> 1-CMRA-971,1-CMRZ-121 ,1-CMRZ-165

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage multi search API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html). Send two queries here - one with exact match and other with token matches. In your code you could decide which one to take.

If you are happy to do it in two calls then you could do them one by one and only do second if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "should" boolean condition for that, with a term query for the exact match, and add a boost to have it first, then a match for the accounts that are similar to your id.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-bool-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-term-query.html#

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-match-query.html

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        {"term" : { "id" : "CMRZ", "boost": 3.0 }},
        {"match": {"id": {"query": "CMRZ"}}
      ]
}}}
```